# New-Team - User is not an owner to perform migration of this Group to Team

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

When trying to make a standard group (unifiedgroup) to teams group I get this message

```
$team = New-Team -Group $group.GroupId
```

Error:

```
New-Team : Error occurred while executing
Code: AccessDenied
Message: User is not an owner to perform migration of this Group to Team
```

Where do I set this permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, all users with a mailbox in Exchange Online have permissions to create Office 365 groups and therefore a team within Microsoft Teams.

You can have tighter control and restrict the creation of new teams and thus the creation of new Office 365 groups by delegating group creation and management rights to a set of users.

For instructions, see [Manage who can create Office 365 Groups](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-who-can-create-office-365-groups-4c46c8cb-17d0-44b5-9776-005fced8e618?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

For more information, please review the following link:

[Assign team owners and members in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/assign-roles-permissions#permissions-to-create-teams)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I've turned of the posibility to create groups by default (powershell). So there is something with the security group